# ARCore selfie front camera with depth

Tags: android, arcore

I'm developing an app for Android using ARCore,
I'm tying to get the depth of each frame using the Depth API but for some reason when I configs the session on selfie camera, depth is not supported but when I'm on front camera depth is supported.
Accordingly to ARCore docs, Depth API is supported for any device which been testing by google. The Depth API is only depends on the phone processing power and doesn't use any sensors
If that so, why on selfie the Depth API isn't supported?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like right now google doesn't allow to acquire or don't support depth image from the front camera although they are proud to say they don't need any special hardware for it.
Even for phon who do have depth sensor on the front camera or two cameras and by the camera configuration do support it throw unknown error when try the depth try to be acquired